# How To Copy/Paste Partial Row

Tags: vba, copy, row, paste, partial

The following macro does everything it is designed for, EXCEPT the copy/paste portion. I am at a loss what correction/s to make.

The macro searches each sheet, specific column (either F or G), seeking any value greater than ZERO. If found, it should copy Cols B:F or B:G (depending on which column was searched) and paste those values to the appropriate worksheet.

Thank you for your assistance !

```
Option Explicit

Sub SampleCopy()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
    
'On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
           
    Select Case ws.Name
        
        Case "In Stock", "To Order", "Sheet1"
            'If it's one of these sheets, do nothing
           
        Case Else
            
               For Each c In Range("F15:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row)
                  If c.Value >= 1 Then
                       Range("B:G").Copy Sheets("In Stock").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(1)  'Edit sheet name
                  End If
               Next c
            
               For Each c In Range("G15:G50" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)
                   If c.Value >= 1 Then
                       Range("B:G").Copy Sheets("To Order").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(1)  'Edit sheet name
                   End If
               Next c
          
        End Select
    Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

[Download Example WB](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/lLqLR16aMQB2gyLjCH93ZWupeMJZyNbAeIVtC1Vuvld)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Pay attention to the explicit indication of the sheet  `ws.Range`,`ws.Cells` and the need to fill in cells `B14` on the sheets `In Stock`,`To Order` to correctly determine the last rows in the tables in case are they empty:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SampleCopy()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    
'On Error Resume Next

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
           
    Select Case ws.Name
        
        Case "In Stock", "To Order", "Sheet1"
            'If it's one of these sheets, do nothing
           
        Case Else
                
               For Each c In ws.Range("F15:F" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row)
                  If c.Value > 0 Then
                       Set rngToCopy = Intersect(ws.Columns("B:G"), c.EntireRow)
                       If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                            rngToCopy.Copy Sheets("In Stock").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, rngToCopy.Columns.Count) 'Edit sheet name
                       End If
                  End If
               Next c
            
               For Each c In ws.Range("G15:G" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)
                   If c.Value > 0 Then
                       Set rngToCopy = Intersect(ws.Columns("B:G"), c.EntireRow)
                       If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                            rngToCopy.Copy Sheets("To Order").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, rngToCopy.Columns.Count)  'Edit sheet name
                       End If
                   End If
               Next c
          
        End Select
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You sir are a god send ! Thank you so much !